# Create a tensor with ones where another tensor has non-zero elements in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

Say I have a tensor A with any shape. It has a number k of non-zero elements. I want to build another tensor B, with 1s where A is non zero and 0s where A is zero.

For example:

```
A = [[1,2,0],
     [0,3,0],
     [0,0,5]]
```

then B will be :

```
B = [[1,1,0],
     [0,1,0],
     [0,0,1]]
```

Is there a simple way to implement this in Pytorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's:

```
B = (A!=0).int()
```

Also:

```
B = A.bool().int()
```